# How do I look at the text value of a label?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch

I am really getting frustrated now!  I have a new problem now, all I want to do is say if

lblMessage.Text = "30 Seconds" then do some code 
otherwise do some other code

```
if (lblMessage.text isEqualToString:@"30 Seconds")
{
    NSString *strPlayerAtTable = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@ at table", ActivePlayer];
    lblMessage.text = strPlayerAtTable;
}
else
if (nStopClockPos == 30)
{
    lblTime.textColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
    lblMessage.text = @"30 Seconds";
}
```

I get the error Expected ) before isEqualToString

Have I got to put it into a new string variable or something?

Cheers

Paul

Comment: BTW, you are leaking `strPlayerAtTable`. Add `[strPlayerAtTable release];` after assigning it to `lblMessage.text`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try adding brackets in the if statement to actually call the NSString comparison method:

```
if ([lblMessage.text isEqualToString:@"30 Seconds"])
```

Comment: Explanation: `isEqualToString:` is not an operator; you need to send an `isEqualToString:` *message*, and in order to do that, you need a message expression, which is always enclosed in square brackets. This even applies within the round brackets (a.k.a. parenthetical marks) of the `if` statement's condition.

Comment: Other explanation: `lblMessage.text` is an `NSString` object and as a member of this class it has a method called `isEqualToString:(NSString *)`. So you need to call that method (this is done using square brackets) and pass as an argument the NSString you want to compare it against (in this case `@"30 Seconds"`).